# What is the difference between backfill and catchup in airflow

Tags: airflow

I am trying to understand catchup and backfill in airflow. I understood what catchup is but I have not completely understood what backfill exactly is and how it is used.

I have read the documentation but but couldn't find good example to understand backfill.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the documentation Backfill and Catchup are the same thing [1](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scheduler.html#backfill-and-catchup).
If the `catchup` parameter is set to `True` in your DAG arguments, then the Airflow scheduler will perform Backfill, i.e. it will perform all the missing DAG Runs between your `start_date` and your potential `end_date`.

Comment: backfill CLI command can run for dates before the start date of the dag but catchup cannot, so there's some minor different I find

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the previous accepted answer's link is broken, and when I looked, I did not find they are the same thing, although very similar. Here is the documentation outlining catchup - https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dag-run.html#catchup with backfill being defined right below.

Backfill is a manual operation you can run in the command line while catchup is an attribute you can set directly on the DAG. I also can't verify this in the documentation, but backfill will run in parallel to your other DAGs, while I *believe* catchup will be executed by the scheduler and will be part of the normal DAG process.

Possibly a little pedantic, but adding backfill=False on a DAG won't work, and running

```
airflow dags catchup \
    --start-date START_DATE \
    --end-date END_DATE \
    dag_id
```

won't work. When I first read the current accepted answer, I personally thought that catchup was a deprecated keyword to mean *same thing* as backfill, which is not the case.